# an exception accured while using HBaseContext

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to bulk load the data into HBase using Spark with HBaseContext, but i am getting the exception below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/StoreFileWriter
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1475)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:472)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:369)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have hbase-client and Hadoop-client in your dependencies